# How to change the screen saver wait time, which is set through Group Policy?

Tags: windows-10, group-policy, screensaver

Is it possible to change the screen saver wait time, when the group policy defines, that the screensaver can not be changed? For example with a powershell script?

I don't have access to the domain controller, so I can't change this policy, but I'm a local administrator. It's a Windows 10 installation.

Answer (score 0):

Not on any kind of long term basis.  You might be able to temporarily override it,but it will revert at the next policy refresh.

See this [related question](https://serverfault.com/questions/593937/can-i-override-domain-group-policy-with-local-group-policy-as-a-local-admin/593945).

That being said, you *may* be able to set your screen saver to `(None)` to bypass the screen saver altogether, assuming your group policy or some other script isn't specifying which screen saver to use.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! How can I realise this in a power shell script? I'll run it periodically. This setting is so freaking annoying. I need to get rid of it...

Comment: The *best* thing to do is ask your administrator for an exception or an extended screen saver lock.  They may have very good reasons for implementing the lock, like compliance with company policies, business certifications, or other regulatory bodies.  That being said, there are [USB mouse jigglers](https://www.cru-inc.com/products/wiebetech/mouse_jiggler/) for sale which are designed to keep a computer awake for forensic and other purposes. Just don't forget to unplug it when you're away.

Comment: There are also software methods of keeping the PC active, such as the popular Caffeine program.